# Robolectric unable to find resource ID when running test

Tags: java, android, android-studio, robolectric

I am new to Robolectric testing in Android Studio and when I try to run tests, the same error appears which states `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x0 in packages`. I made sure that the JUnit Working Directory was $MODULE_DIR$, but it still didn't work. Adding `testOptions.unitTests.includeAndroidResources` to my build.gradle file doesn't do anything either. Here is what the test file looks like:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)  
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)  
public class StartActivityTests {

    StartActivity activity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(StartActivity.class)
            .create()
            .resume()
            .get();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldNotBeNull() throws Exception
    {
        assertNotNull(activity);
    }

    @Test
    public void clickingNewGame_shouldStartAvatarRoomActivity() {
        StartActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(StartActivity.class);
        activity.findViewById(R.id.newUserButtonFirstPage).performClick();

        Intent expectedIntent = new Intent(activity, AvatarRoomActivity.class);
        Intent actual = ShadowApplication.getInstance().getNextStartedActivity();
        assertEquals(expectedIntent.getComponent(), actual.getComponent());
    }
}
```

Please help! It would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note, as of Android Studio 4.1.2, `$MODULE_DIR$` has been replaced with `$ContentRoot$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my SDK to 27 in the build.gradle file and the Robolectric tests succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android Gradle Plugin 3.0 or above, you need to add the following snippet with the android block of build.gradle

```
testOptions {
    unitTests {
        includeAndroidResources = true
    }
}
```

or no Android resource can be found in unit tests.